# Reading matrix from text file into array

Tags: python-3.x

I have the file matrix.txt, which is:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and I'm trying to read through it line by line, and split each line into an array. Right now, I have the following snippet:

```
with open('matrix.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            l.append(map(int, line.split()))
    print(l)
```

But that gives me the output:

```
[<map object at 0x105af8ba8>, <map object at 0x105af8c50>, <map object at 0x105af8cf8>, <map object at 0x105af8e10>, <map object at 0x105af8da0>, <map object at 0x105af8b70>, <map object at 0x105af8400>, <map object at 0x105af8a90>, <map object at 0x105b07128>, <map object at 0x105b071d0>, <map object at 0x105b07240>, <map object at 0x105b073c8>, <map object at 0x105af8c88>, <map object at 0x105b070f0>, <map object at 0x105b074a8>, <map object at 0x105b07518>, <map object at 0x105b075c0>, <map object at 0x105b076a0>]
```

when what I really want is arrays of integers, so that I can iterate through the arrays and extract specific values as needed, and print their corresponding row and column indices in the matrix. What am I messing up?

Comment: did you try this? -- l.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])

Comment: @Tomer I did and ran into a problem--check out the comment on TinyTheBrontosaurus' reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. I think it's the map that is throwing you off. I'm assuming you want l to be a list of list of integers (or array of array of integers). Your code is a list of maps of integers. Replace your l.append line with:

```
l.append( [int(n) for n in line.split()] )
```

A map is a more advanced data structure than a list/array and isn't the right data structure to use for this type of matrix.

Comment: When I run: 

        `l = []

with open('matrix.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            l.append([int(n) for n in line.split()])
    print(l)`

I get the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 5, in <module>
    l.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 5, in <listcomp>
    l.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0,0,0,0,0,0'`

Comment: Your file has commas instead of spaces. Replace split() with split(',') or fix the input file

Comment: My man! Thank you immensely for taking the time, people like you make this community great!

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with everything else

Comment: `map` isn’t a data structure in Python, it’s an operation over lists. (What other languages might call a map Python calls a `dict`.) `map` is entirely appropriate here, but its result needs to be forced from a generator to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of map.

```
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if len(line) > 0:
       l.append([int(a) for a in line.split()])
print(l)
```